# "Главным образом"

Tags: пунктуация

Нужно ли выделять запятыми оборот "главным образом"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Нет, выражение "главным образом", стоящее в середине предложения, запятыми не выделяется.
Пример: *"В Крыму отдыхают главным образом жители Украины и России"*.
Перед ним  может быть запятая, если "главным образом" начинает собой второе простое предложение в составе сложного.
Пример: *"Летом многие поехали в Крым, гланым образом это были жители Украины и России"*.

Answer (score 0):

Выражение "главным образом "вводным словом не является,поэтому запятыми не выделяется.

Answer (score 0):

"Главным образом" обычно употребляется в значении наречия: преимущественно

Читает главным образом журналы = читает преимущественно журналы).

Но в качестве вводного слова входит в состав присоединительной конструкции, поэтому выделяется запятыми вместе с ней здесь:

С полсотни людей, главным образом офицеров,  толпились невдалеке.